# does wp_insert_term link the term to a certain post ID?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

I'm using `wp_insert_term`to add a custom taxonomy like this:

```
wp_insert_term(
     $_POST['city'], // the term 
     'property-city', // the taxonomy
     array(
         'description'=> $_POST['city'],
         'slug' => $_POST['city']
     )
);
```

It does the job, but it doesn't link this term to a certain post ID. Thus, my questions are:
what does wp_insert_term do specifically? Does it just insert the term? If so, how can I link this term to a specific post ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `wp_insert_term()` only creates the term. To assign the term to a post use [`wp_set_object_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms)

```
wp_set_object_terms( $object_id, $terms, $taxonomy, $append );
```